# twist and product of projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, projective-schemes

On $\mathbb P^n_k\times_k \mathbb P^m_k$, is it true that $T_{\mathbb P^n_k\times_k \mathbb P^m_k}\otimes \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n_k\times_k \mathbb P^m_k}(d,e)\simeq p_1^*T_{\mathbb P^n_k}(d)\oplus p_2^*T_{\mathbb P^m_k}(e)$ ? ($n,m\geq 1$ and $p_i$ are the two projections).

Comment: What is $T$? $\textbf{}$

Comment: $T$ is the tangent bundle.

Comment: It seems wrong. One should have $p_1^*T_{\mathbb P^n_k}(d)\otimes p_2^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^m_k}(e) + p_2^*T_{\mathbb P^m_k}(e)\otimes p_1^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n_k}(d)$